# Recalculate normal on editable poly object

Tags: 3dsmax, autodesk, maxscript

I'm working on a exporter, but the problem I'm stuck at is the normal calculation.

I've been reading many posts about this, and it seems like the "getnormal" function does not work like intended. (this is the one creating wrong results for my exporter).

So I need to recalculate it manually.

The question is - How do I do this?
the part that calculates the normal now looks like this:

If you provide a function, then please keep in mind this code below, I'd like to not rewrite everything.

thanks in advance.

```
   for i = 1 to num_faces do
    (
     face = getFace Obj i

     v1 = (MeshArrays[2].count + 1)
     v2 = (MeshArrays[2].count + 2)
     v3 = (MeshArrays[2].count + 3)

     append MeshArrays[1] [v1,v2,v3]

     v1 = coordsys world getvert Obj face.x
     v2 = coordsys world getvert Obj face.y
     v3 = coordsys world getvert Obj face.z


     append MeshArrays[2] v1
     append MeshArrays[2] v2
     append MeshArrays[2] v3

     v1 = (coordsys local getnormal Obj face.x) -- * theInvTM 
     v2 = (coordsys local getnormal Obj face.y) --* theInvTM 
     v3 = (coordsys local getnormal Obj face.z) --* theInvTM 

     append MeshArrays[4] v1
     append MeshArrays[4] v2
     append MeshArrays[4] v3 

     if Obj.numtverts != 0 then 
     ( 
      tvface = getTVFace Obj i
      v1 = getTVert Obj tvface.x
      v2 = getTVert Obj tvface.y
      v3 = getTVert Obj tvface.z
      append MeshArrays[3] v1
      append MeshArrays[3] v2 
      append MeshArrays[3] v3 
     )


    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resolved it by replacing the appropriate lines with the following code:

```
--get the object's transformation
myTransform = Obj.transform

-- get the normal * transformation - translation
v1 = (coordsys local getnormal Obj face.x)* myTransform  - (myTransform.translationpart)
v2 = (coordsys local getnormal Obj face.y)* myTransform  - (myTransform.translationpart)
v3 = (coordsys local getnormal Obj face.z) * myTransform - (myTransform.translationpart)

--normalize them / and write normal to a new variable
v11 = normalize v1
v22 = normalize v2
v33 = normalize v3

--append to array
append MeshArrays[4] v11
append MeshArrays[4] v22
append MeshArrays[4] v33
```